# jQuery is not working well

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one form in which I have an address field where the user can enter many addresses. It's up to the user. They can enter many addresses, it's working fine.

I am checking that the user doesn't enter the same address twice. For this I wrote some jQuery code.

```
jQuery('#EnrollmentEnrollUserForm').submit(function(){
  // alert(jQuery('#EnrollmentServiceAddress1').val());
  // alert(jQuery('.premise-body').html());
  var add=jQuery('#EnrollmentServiceAddress1').val();
  add=add.toLowerCase();
  var address_string =jQuery('table.premise_details').find('tr:first td:last').html();
  // alert(address_string);
  var address = address_string.split('::');
  address[0]=address[0].toLowerCase();
  // alert(address[0]);
  if(add==address[0]){
  alert("These premises already exist. Please enter other premises.");
    return false;
  }
  // checking whether a premise added is same as the added premises or not
  // var premise_check = true;
  var retval = true;
  jQuery('table.premise_details').each(function() {
    var address_string = jQuery(this).find('tr:first td:last').html();
    // alert(jQuery(this).find('tr:first td:last').html());
    var address = address_string.split('::');
    address[0]=address[0].toLowerCase();
    // alert(address[0]);
    if(add==(address[0])){
      alert("These premises were already added... Please enter other premises.");
      retval = false;
    }
  });
  if(!retval){
    return false;
  }
});
```

This code works only sometimes. The problem I am facing is, it's showing an alert if the user enters the same address again, but the page is loading in an infinite loop.

Can anybody tell me what's the problem with that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tagged PHP but there is no PHP.

Comment: add this for a start:   ...retval = false; return false; }

Comment: Did you know that you only have to write `jQuery` in its long form once? By wrapping your code in `(function($) { .... })(jQuery);`, you can use `$` no matter if `noConflict` has been used or not.

Comment: @ThiefMaster is this jquery conflict problem?

Comment: @vlzvl I did that but not working??

Comment: is this code wrapped into $(document).ready(function() { .. }); ?

Comment: @Learner: No, it was mainly a suggestion to make your code more readable.

Comment: @vlzvl yes.. i wrapped that code already...

Comment: the same happen in other browsers too? which is the one tested? what js error console says?

Comment: @vlzvl it is not showing any error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('#EnrollmentEnrollUserForm').submit(function(){
  var add=jQuery('#EnrollmentServiceAddress1').val();

  add=add.toLowerCase();

  var address_string =jQuery('table.premise_details').find('tr:first td:last').html();

  var address = address_string.split('::');

  address[0]=address[0].toLowerCase();

  if(add==address[0]){

  alert("These premises already exist. Please enter other premises.");

    return false;

  }

  jQuery('table.premise_details').each(function() {

    var address_string = jQuery(this).find('tr:first td:last').html();

    var address = address_string.split('::');

    address[0]=address[0].toLowerCase();

    if(add==(address[0])){

      alert("These premises were already added... Please enter other premises.");

    return false;

    }

  });

});
```

The reason why you are getting issue is you have call checking your retval after you are finishing you loop of each function, show its taking last set value of retval and creating issue for you, here i have change code and returning false as i match my condtion .
I have edited code.. please check this code

Comment: thanks but, I checked that... before my code was like this only.. it is showing same error.. that's y before i used retval variable for that...

Comment: Okey .. Placed you retval condition inside your each fuunction.. I you found it working please vote for this answer

Answer (score 0):

Now it is working fine..

```
jQuery('#EnrollmentEnrollUserForm').submit(function(){
              var add=jQuery('#EnrollmentServiceAddress1').val();
              add=add.toLowerCase();
                            // checking whether a premise added is same as the added premise or not
                jQuery('table.premise_details').each(function() { 
                    var address_string = jQuery(this).find('tr:first td:last').html();
                    var address = address_string.split('::');
                    address[0]=address[0].toLowerCase();
                        if(add==(address[0])){
                            alert("This premise is already added... Please enter other premise.");
                            return false;
                        }
                });
    });
```